# Can I write() to a socket just after connect() call, but before TCP connection established?

Tags: sockets, tcp

My experiment showed that I can write to a non-blocking socket just after the `connect()` call, with no TCP connection established yet, and the written data correctly received by the peer after connection occured (asynchronously). Is this guaranteed on Linux / FreeBSD? I mean, will `write()` return > 0 when the connection is still in progress? Or maybe I was lucky and the TCP connection was successfully established between the `connect()` and `write()` calls?

The experiment code:

```
int fd = socket (PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK)

struct sockaddr_in addr;
memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(_ip_port.port);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(_ip_port.ipv4);

int res = connect(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));

// HERE: res == -1, errno == 115 (EINPROGRESS)

int r = ::write(fd, "TEST", 4);

// HERE: r == 4
```

P.S.
I process multiple listening and connecting sockets (incoming and outgoing connections) in single thread and manage them by epoll. Usually, when I want to create a new outgoing connection, I call non-blocking `connect()` and wait the `EPOLLOUT` (epoll event) and then `write()` my data. But I noticed that I can begin writing before the `EPOLLOUT` and get appropriate result. Can I trust this approach or should I use my old fashion approach?

P.P.S.
I repeated my experiment with a remote host with latency 170ms and got different results: the `write()` (just after `connect()`) returned -1 with `errno == EAGAIN`. So, yes, my first experiment was not fair (connecting to fast localhost), but still I think the "`write()` just next to `connect()`" can be used: if `write()` returned -1 and EAGAIN, I wait the `EPOLLOUT` and retry writing. But I agree, this is dirty and useless approach.

Comment: IIRC for nin-blocking sockets, connect() behaves differently. You should wait (via select or poll) for the socket to become  writable

Comment: Obviously the connect completed between the calls. You got lucky. Don't write code like this. There's really no point in doing a connect in non-blocking mode unless you have multiple aockets. Connect in blocking mode and then switch.

Comment: NB There is nothing 'old-fashioned' about your approach using `poll()`. It is merely correct. Correctness is not a function of time.

Comment: Re your edit, the approach you now mention isn't the same one you're asking about.

Answer (score 4):

*Can I write() to a socket just after connect() call, but before TCP connection established?*

Sure, you *can*.  It's just likely to fail.

Per the [POSIX specification of `write()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html):

> [ECONNRESET]
>
> A write was attempted on a socket that is not connected.

Per the [Linux man page for `write()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html):

> **EDESTADDRREQ**
>
> fd refers to a datagram socket for which a peer address has
>   not been set using `connect(2)`.

If the TCP connect has not completed, your `write()` call will fail.

Comment: @pavelkolodin You seem to be just quibbling. What was meant was perfectly clear, and should be even more so now.

Comment: I find this answer unsatisfactory as it is not clear at all what "a socket that is not connected" means in this context. Perhaps it means that no call to connect() was done. I think that ECONNRESET is the error that one gets when the connection is 'reset by peer'; that is, it is a result of receiving an icmp packet from the host that you try to write to. I can imagine that if a connection is already in progress that this will never happen (as a result of how the TCP works).

Answer (score 0):

At least on Linux, the socket is marked as not writable until the [SYN, ACK] is received from the peer. This means the system will not send any application data over the network until the [SYN, ACK] is received.

If the socket is in non-blocking mode, you must use select/poll/epoll to wait until it becomes writable (otherwise `write` calls will fail with `EAGAIN` and no data will be enqueued). When the socket becomes writable, the kernel has usually already sent an empty [ACK] message to the peer before the application has had time to write the first data, which results in some unnecessary overhead due to the API design.

What appears to be working is to after calling `connect` on a non-blocking socket and getting `EINPROGRESS`, set the socket to blocking and then start to write data. Then the kernel will internally first wait until the [SYN, ACK] is received from the peer and then send the application data and the initial ACK in a single packet, which will avoid that empty [ACK]. Note that the `write` call will block until [SYN, ACK] is received and will e.g. return -1 with errno `ECONNREFUSED`, `ETIMEDOUT` etc. if the connection fails. This approach however does not work in WSL 1 (Windows Subsystem for Linux), which just fails will `EPIPE` immediately (no `SIGPIPE` though).

In any case, not much can be done to eliminate this initial round-trip time due to the design of TCP. If the TCP Fast Open (TFO) feature is supported by both endpoints however, and can accept its security issues, this round-trip can be eliminated. See https://lwn.net/Articles/508865/ for more info.